# What is the plus sign before a function?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the JS code from bootstrap.js

```
/* ========================================================================
 * Bootstrap: collapse.js v3.1.1
 * http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse
 * ========================================================================
 * Copyright 2011-2014 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 * ======================================================================== */


+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  // COLLAPSE PUBLIC CLASS DEFINITION
  // ================================
   ...
  }
```

I've seen ";" before a function to avoid mixing code before the function definition. But what does the "+" sign mean before the function mean? Is it going to convert the return to String?

Comment: You basically missed the most important part of the code, the last pair of parenthesis.

Answer (score 10):

It is normally used with IIFE/SIFE. When you use `+` sign like that, it evaluates the expression following that, so when you put it in a function, it executes even an anonymous function, like this

```
+function(){
    console.log("Welcome");
}()
```

**Output**

```
Welcome
```

It is another way to get the same behavior when the entire function is enclosed with parenthesis, like this

```
(function(){
    console.log("Welcome");
}());
```

**Note**: Not only `+`, any unary arithmetic operator will give the same result.

Answer (score 1):

It's called **[unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_())**:

> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its
>   operand but attempts to converts it into a number, if it isn't
>   already. For example, y = +x takes the value of x and assigns that to
>   y; that is, if x were 3, y would get the value 3 and x would retain
>   the value 3; but if x were the string "3", y would also get the value
>   3

Comment: True, but this usage has nothing to do with any numeric result ..